# How to catch unhandled error in Deferred originating from threads.deferToThread()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, twisted

I'm getting the error Unhandled error in Deferred:
 Can anybody help, how to handle this?

```
    @inlineCallbacks
    def start(self):
        # First we try Avahi, if it fails we fallback to Bluetooth because
        # the receiver may be able to use only one of them
        log.info("Trying to use this code with Avahi: %s", self.userdata)
        key_data = yield threads.deferToThread(self.discovery.find_key, self.userdata)
        if key_data and not self.stopped:
            success = True
            message = ""
            returnValue((key_data, success, message))
        if self.bt_code and not self.stopped:
            # We try Bluetooth, if we have it
            log.info("Trying to connect to %s with Bluetooth", self.bt_code)
            self.bt = BluetoothReceive(self.bt_port)
            msg_tuple = yield self.bt.find_key(self.bt_code, self.mac)
            key_data, success, message = msg_tuple
            if key_data:
                # If we found the key
            returnValue((key_data, success, message))
```

Error throws at line

```
key_data = yield threads.deferToThread(self.discovery.find_key, self.userdata)
```

Comment: functions can raise exceptions (deferreds can fire failures).  What's your question?

Comment: Hello @Jean-PaulCalderone I'm getting an error "Unhandled error in Deferred:" and my program crashes. I want to handle it gracefully by logging a message like("key_data not found") instead of "unhandled error in deffered"

Answer (score 4):

This is the way that makes sense for most devs using `inlineCallbacks`

```
try:
    key_data = yield threads.deferToThread(self.discovery.find_key, self.userdata)
except Exception as e:
    log.exception('Unable to get key_data')
    returnValue(e)
```

Another way would be to chain callback using `addCallback` (success) and `addErrback` (failure). So you should be able to do something like this:

```
d = threads.deferToThread(self.discovery.find_key, self.userdata)    # notice there's no yield
d.addCallback(success_callback)
d.addErrback(failure_callback)
key_data = yield d
```

## Helpful Links

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html#simple-failure-handling
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html

Comment: Thank you so much @notorious.no, it helped :)

Comment: chaining addcallback method worked for me. However the try..except method throws this "keysign.discover (DEBUG): Unable to get key_data
Unhandled error in Deferred:
"

Answer (score 0):

Per the [inlineCallbacks documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html#inline-callbacks-using-yield) you can handle this case with a try/except statement:

For example:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def getUsers(self):
    try:
        responseBody = yield makeRequest("GET", "/users")
    except ConnectionError:
       log.failure("makeRequest failed due to connection error")
       returnValue([])

    returnValue(json.loads(responseBody))
```

Therefore, replace your `key_data = yield ...` line with:

```
try:
    key_data = yield threads.deferToThread(self.discovery.find_key, self.userdata)
except SomeExceptionYouCanHandle:
    # Some exception handling code
```